# Post request stuck pending when returning a cookie

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

Im learning to use JWT. I setup a very simple react app and an express server that uses a json file as database to try it but when i return a cookie via `res.cookie` the request is stuck on pending according to my browsers network tab.

This is how my server looks

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const { JsonDB, Config } = require("node-json-db");
require("dotenv").config();

const server = express();

server.use(express.json());
server.use(cors());
server.use(cookieParser());

const db = new JsonDB(new Config("db", true, false));

server.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  const data = await db.getData("/users");

  const user = data.find((user) => {
    return user.username === username && user.password === password;
  });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(403).json({
      error: "invalid login",
    });
  }

  const token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.MY_SECRET, { expiresIn: "1h" });

  return res.cookie("token", token, { httpOnly: true });
});

server.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  console.log("cleared token");
  return res.clearCookie("token");
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server listening on port 3000");
});
```

And this is my request in my react app

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const username = usernameRef.current.value;
    const password = passwordRef.current.value;

    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login", {
      username: username,
      password: password,
    });

    console.log(response);
  };
```

I've tried changing the order of the middlewares around and adding `next()` at the end but didn't work. Sending data via `res.send` works just fine. I've worked with express about a year ago but never ran into this.

Answer (score 0):

`res.cookie` only set cookie. It doesn't response to client. After `res.cookie`, use `res.send`, `res.json` or any method to response.